# How to Insert Ads After Every X Paragraph PHP

Tags: php

I am currently using this code to insert Ads after the 5th paragraph and it works just fine.

```
//Insert ads after fifth paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
    $ad_code = '<center>AD CODE</center>';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 5, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

// Parent Function
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

But, I would like the ads to be repeated after every 5 paragraphs, not just once. What do I do?

Comment: You need to change the `if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {` line. You could e.g. use mod, or a separate index variable you increment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After every 4th paragraph specific content will show, you can replace the script code with your own.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'theme_slug_the_content_filter', 10, 1);
function theme_slug_the_content_filter($content) {
   if( is_single() ) {
      $parags = explode('</p>', $content);
      $count = 0;
      $content_new = '';
        
      foreach( $parags as $key => $item ) {
        if( $count % 4 == 0 ) {
            $parags[$key] .= '<br><br><script async data-uid="8b1ab15ffc" src="https://example.com/8b1ab15ffc/index.js"></script>';  // this script code
        }
            $count++;
        }
    
        foreach ($parags as $parag) {
            $content_new .= $parag;
        }
        return $content_new;
     }
     else {
        return $content;
     }
}
```